# Opening app from last opened UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I need my app to remember which was the last `UIViewController` opened so when the app is loaded out of memory, I substitute a `rootViewController` property in the `AppDelegate` with one saved in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    frontViewController = [[SGLoginScreenViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

What I want to do is to put some code in the `ViewDidLoad` method of each `ViewController` and remember its name in `NSUserDefaults` to later use it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, something like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self forKey:@"currentViewController"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The problem is, however, that XCode is giving me this warning:

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<SGMainScreenFirstTimeViewController: 0x8e1fea0>' of class 'SGMainScreenFirstTimeViewController'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

Any ideas on how to implement this whole thing right? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only save in user defaults objects that can conform to the Key-Value coding (NSString, NSnumber, etc). Converting class to string and recreating class knowing class name would be the way to go for what you wish to achieve.
This would be a good approach for saving in NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSStringFromClass([self class]); forKey:@"currentViewController"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And for loading back you recreate the class based on the saved string, as below:

```
NSString *savedClassName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"];
UIViewController *controller = [(UIViewController *)NSClassFromString(savedClassName) alloc] init];
```

Comment: How does the compiler know what is 'classStringSavedInUserDefaults'?

Comment: It doesnt saves the control values present in UIViewcontroller. For example, if i have a UITextField with value "sample" then it doesnt recover the value. Is there any way that i can save the control along with its values

Comment: You can save additional values in NSUserDefaults, and load them when your view controller loads.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUSerDefaults` is basically to store default values... not big objects *( list of items that can be saved includes (NSString,NSData,NSDictionary,NSArray,NSNumber)* ..keep that in mind next time.

better way to do the functionality.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Second View" forKey:@"currentViewController"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and then on app Load

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"] isEqualToString:@"Second View"])
{
//your code/logic
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. For `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, their contents must be property list objects.

So you can save name of your view controller and restore it on start, knowing its name

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can't save mutable values in NSUserDefaults.  just check the psudocode  following :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"nibnameofcurrentViewController" forKey:@"currentViewController"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

when your app launch again then do following:

```
UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:[[NSUserDefault standerdDefault]objectForkey:@"currentViewController"] bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```